# microsoft ace oledb 12 is not registered on the local machine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I installed Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable(X_64bit). How do you fix this on Windows 10 64 bit pc, 32 bit Office 2016, Windows 10?

Not able to upload excel file.at connection open its throwing error  The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Comment: ACE is available in two different versions of "bitness" - 32bit and 64bit. If you ahve the 64 bit driver installed and you're writing a 32bit program, or vice versa, then your program won't be able to find the driver. Additionally, ACE 12 relates to Office 2007 or Access Data Engine 2010 redistributable. 2016 is a different version of ACE (possibly 16 - I've never looked. It's supremely confusing and annoying that Jet/Ace engine numerical versions don't necessarily align with the year on the marketing packaging - https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/history/versions.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) to easily read excel files. There is also EPPlus which has the ability to create excel files for export functionality on your application.